# Any option prestashop CMS pages siderbar are different in page wise?

Tags: prestashop

I'm creating two CMS pages.

Ex:
Page1, Page 2.

Page1 Left-Sidebar showing Some content

And Page2 Left-Sidebar showing Different content or links.

It's possible in Prestashoh? If how to solve this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with default prestashop behavior. You have to create a module to manage it yourself, override/update the current sidebar used to change display depending on the current cms or put the sidebar inside the created CMS pages, and then display them right with css.

Like always, the best solution in my opinion is to create your own module. It should be an easy feature to implement.